# Difference of sunset time per minute by altitude?

Tags: astronomy

For what difference of altitude needed for the sunset time to differ by a minute?

How to calculate that?

Comment: Do you really mean *altitude*? Or *latitude*?

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Altitude in kilometer

Comment: @Martin are you looking for a approximate thumb rule kind of thing or a fully accurate rigorous and more involved method ?

Comment: @silverrahul Anything will be helpful for me. I want to know about this. I guess it cannot be always fully accurate. But how do the astronomers consider this and make their calculations?

Comment: The full solution would need much spherical trigonometry.
The general result will depend on geographical latitude and on the time within the year.
An easy special case would be, when the observer is at the equator of the earth,
and the sun is at the equator of the sky (i.e. on March 21, or Spetember 23).

Comment: Take a look on the astronomy.stackexchange for an [approximate (rambly) analytical solution](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/19623/22239) or an [exact solution but using a Python library](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/36508/22239).

Comment: The approximate figure is , for every 1.5 km of altitude the sunset is delayed by 1 minute